# Uso de cadena de strings en python

Tags: python-3.7

En python 3 tengo que hacer lo siguiente:

```
significado= <3*corazon$:)*carita feliz$:(*carita triste$....

traduccion= CORAZON CARITA FELIZ CARITA TRISTE
```

Tengo que solo cortar y pasar a mayúsculas las palabras entre `*` y `$` pero no sé como hacerlo... ayuda plis

Answer (score 0):

Se soluciona con expresiones regulares. La expresión necesaria para reconocer los textos es `"\*(.*?)\$"`. Usamos la barra `\` para que `*` y `$` se interpreten en forma literal, no como metacaracteres.

Si usaramos `.*` a secas, capturariamos la cadena completa, pero lo que nos interesa es captura sólo hasta el `?` más cercano. Para eso usamos `.*?`. Luego encerramos este patrón entre paréntesis, para indicar que queremos *capturar* el texto reconocido. El método retornará una lista con los textos reconocidos.

El siguiente código extrae los nombres convertidos a mayúsculas:

```
import re

patron = re.compile("\*(.*?)\$")
significado= "<3*corazon$:)*carita feliz$:(*carita triste$"
m = patron.findall(significado.upper())
if m:
    print(m)
```

`m` es una lista con los nombres:

```
['CORAZON', 'CARITA FELIZ', 'CARITA TRISTE']
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @Candid Moe esta muy bien, sin embargo si tu dices que no puedes usar nada que no hayas visto aun, y que mejor seria con ciclos, pues aquí te traigo mi solución (no tome en cuenta la eficiencia, por lo que talvez se pueda hacer mas eficiente)
Lo hice de 2 formas, cada uno lo agrupe en una función.

**Primera forma**

```py
def metod1():
  #se define el significado
  significado= "<3*corazon$:)*carita feliz$:(*carita triste$"
  #se define los caracteres especiales
  caracteres = ["<3", "$", "*"]
  #aqui se almacenara la nueva palabra traducida
  traducido = []
  # aqui creamo un tipo switch on/off
  upper = False
  
  #recorremos cada palabra de la cadena
  for c in range(len(significado)):
     if significado[c] in caracteres:
       upper = not upper
     if upper:
       letra = significado[c]
       #convertimos en mayusculas
       traducido.append(letra.upper())
  #traducido es una lista ["corazon", "carita feliz",..]
  #utilizamos join para unirla como cadena
  traducido = "".join(traducido)
  #resultado *CORAZON*CARITA FELIZ*CARITA TRISTE

  # separamos la cadena segun el caracter *
  traducido = traducido.split("*")
  #volvemos a unir la lista
  traducido = " ".join(traducido)
  print(traducido)
```

**Segunda forma**

```py
def metod2():
  #lo mismo de antes
  significado= "<3*corazon$:)*carita feliz$:(*carita triste$"
  caracteres = ["<3", "$", "*"]
  
  #que caritas existen
  caritas = [":(",":)"]
  
  #recorremos la lista de caracteres
  #reemplazamos el caracter por un " "(espacio en blanco)
  for s in caracteres:
    significado = significado.replace(s," ")
  #igual remplazamos pero las caritas por un "" 
  for carita in caritas:
    significado = significado.replace(carita,"")
  #pones como mayusculas todo
  significado = significado.upper()
  print(significado)
```

**Probamos**

```py
metod1()
# CORAZON CARITA FELIZ CARITA TRISTE

metod2()
# CORAZON  CARITA FELIZ  CARITA TRISTE
```

Aqui en el metodo 2 nos sale con espacios de mas, no se si sea muy importante pero igual se puede arreglar