# Remplazar valores de una cadena Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bucle-for, variables

me mandaron un trabajo desde la universidad sobre cadenas, y no he sabido como resolverlo;

El programa debe recibir como valores de entrada una cadena de texto que contenga uno o más *emojis*, luego en otra variable de entrada debe recibir el significado de cada *emoji*, ejemplo:

```
texto_str = "Hola <3 como estas :-D"

significado = "<3*corazon$:-D*cara feliz$"
```

Luego el programa debe devolver como salida:

```
"Hola CORAZON como estas CARA FELIZ"
```

De tal forma que que los *emojis* de inculuidos en la cadena de la variable `texto_str` sean remplazados por las palabras incluidas en la variable `significado`.

Hasta ahora he hecho un código y la verdad que no sé si está bien o como continuar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pido disculpas por adjuntar imagen pero es que al copiar el código lo pega mal.

Mi código muestra las siguientes salidas:

> `corazon`

`cara feliz`

`incomodo`

Sería de mucha utilidad para mí que alguien me pudiera aconsejar para poder de esa forma mejorar mi entendimiento sobre cadenas, debido a que no las entiendo y he hecho mi mayor esfuerzo por intentar hacerlo sin ayuda pero no he conseguido avanzar mucho en el tiempo que le he dedicado.

Me complica mucho debido a que no puedo usar métodos, como *remplace*, *append* o *split*, etc.

Comment: Tal vez esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/451266/183782) te sirva, es prácticamente la misma tarea

Comment: bro mira date cuenta que los * se utiliza de separador entre los emoji y la palabra que los relacion y los **$** separan los dos anterior de los siguientes.

con el la funcion `str.split(sep="")` puedes crear arrays que se dividan segun que atributo pasaste en el sep

con eso puedes crear un diccionario y que luego lo compare.

si quieres te puedo brindar una solucion en codigos o dejar que tu lo hagas

Comment: El codigo como va como texto para no reescribirlo

Answer (score 0):

Aqui la respuesta bro

```
texto_str = "Hola <3 como estas :-D"
significado = "<3*corazon$:-D*cara feliz$"


 #definimos array que vamos a usar
 diccionarios = []
 palabrasSepardas = []

 #sepaamos las palabras por "$"
 separacion1 = significado.split(sep='$')

 #creamos un array que nos guarde las palabras en grupos de 2
 for separacion1 in separacion1:
     palabrasSepardas += [separacion1.split(sep='*')]

 #usamos ese grupo de 2 para definir el diccionario y tener cada simbolo con su texto
 for palabraSeparda in palabrasSepardas:
     try:
         diccionarios.append({"simbolo":palabraSeparda[0], "texto":palabraSeparda[1]})
     except:
         pass

 # Buscamos en el texto el simbolo y lo romplazamos por el texto que este asociado
 for diccionario in diccionarios:
      texto_str = texto_str.replace(diccionario["simbolo"], diccionario["texto"])
 print(texto_str)
```

devuelve:

> Hola corazon como estas cara feliz

espero que te sirve y lo comprendas bro, tienes detalles para corregir y optimizar por si quieres seguir mejorando

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, entendí muy bien tu código pero el problema está en que no me dejan usar ni listas ni el método split. Y es ahí donde tengo problemas :( porque no se como hacerlo sin usar esos métodos

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes una posible solucion

Los emojis se cambian por las palabras independientemente de su posición en la cadena o el numero de veces que estén, pero tiene 1 problema

1. Si se pone medio emoji se raya, creo que tiene facil solucion en el principio de las tres funciones de los emojis.

Si mejoro el codigo te lo paso, y si no, espero que te sirva para salir del paso o mejorarlo tu

Salu2

```
texto_new=''
significado = '<3*corazon$:-D*cara feliz$>.<*incomodo$' # No lo he usado
cont = 0
p = 0

def corazon():
    global texto_str, cont, p, texto_new
    a = 0
    for i in texto_str:
        a += 1
        if (i == '<' and cont == 0):
            cont += 1
        elif (i == '3' and cont == 1):
            cont += 1 
            b = a - cont
            # Reescribe el texto <3
            texto_new = 0
            p = 0
            for i in texto_str:
                if (p == 1):
                    if (len(texto_new) == b):
                        i = 'corazon'
                        texto_new = f'{h}{i}'
                        h = texto_new
                        p = cont
                        texto_new = f'{texto_new}{texto_str[a:]}'
                    else:
                        texto_new = f'{h}{i}'
                        h = texto_new
                elif (p == 2):
                    p = 1
                else:
                    h = i
                    texto_new = h
                    p += 1
        else:
            cont = 0
def carafeliz():
    global texto_str, cont, p, texto_new
    a = 0
    for i in texto_str:
        a += 1
        if (i == ':' and cont == 0):
            cont += 1
        elif (i == '-' and cont == 1):
            cont += 1
        elif (i == 'D' and cont == 2):
            cont += 1
            b = a - cont
            # Reescribe el texto :-D
            texto_new = 0
            p = 0
            for i in texto_str:
                if (p == 1):
                    if (len(texto_new) == b):
                        i = 'cara feliz'
                        texto_new = f'{h}{i}'
                        h = texto_new
                        p = cont
                        texto_new = f'{texto_new}{texto_str[a:]}'
                        
                    else:
                        texto_new = f'{h}{i}'
                        h = texto_new
                elif (p >= 2):
                    p -= 1
                else:
                    h = i
                    texto_new = h
                    p += 1
        else:
            cont = 0
def incomodo():
    global texto_str, cont, p, texto_new
    a = 0 # Indica la posición actual del bucle en la cadena
    for i in texto_str:
        a += 1
        if (i == '>' and cont == 0):
            cont += 1
        elif (i == '.' and cont == 1):
            cont += 1
        elif (i == '<' and cont == 2):
            cont += 1
            b = a - cont
            # Reescribe el texto >.<
            texto_new = 0
            p = 0
            for i in texto_str:
                if (p == 1):
                    if (len(texto_new) == b):
                        i = 'incomodo'
                        texto_new = f'{h}{i}'
                        h = texto_new
                        p = cont
                        texto_new = f'{texto_new}{texto_str[a:]}'
                    else:
                        texto_new = f'{h}{i}'
                        h = texto_new
                elif (p >= 2):
                    p -= 1
                else:
                    h = i
                    texto_new = h
                    p += 1
        else:
            cont = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 0
    x2 = 1
    x3 = 1
    texto_str = 'Hola <3, cómo estás? :-D. Voy atrasado a la clase >.<'
    while True:
        if (x == 0):
            corazon()
            if (texto_str == texto_new):
                x += 1
                x2 -= 1
            else:
                texto_str = texto_new
        elif (x2 == 0):
            carafeliz()
            if (texto_str == texto_new):
                x2 += 1
                x3 -= 1
            else:
                texto_str = texto_new
        elif (x3 == 0):
            incomodo()
            if (texto_str == texto_new):
                x3 += 1
            else:
                texto_str = texto_new
        else:
            break

    print(texto_str)
```

> Devuelve: Hola corazon, cómo estás? cara feliz. Voy atrasado a la clase incomodo